# одна и та же команда в sql не работает в php

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, upload

В phpmyadmin нормально работает команда загрузки файла:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\\openserver\\userdata\\php_upload\\test.txt' INTO TABLE a_db.aa(aaa);
```

а в php тот же запрос не срабатывает:

```
<?php
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'a_db');
$mysql->query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\\openserver\\userdata\\php_upload\\test.txt' INTO TABLE a_db.aa(aaa)");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($mysql);
?>
```

можете помочь?

Comment: у тебя php заменяет \\ на \ и в итоге команды выполняемые команды получаются различны в phpmyadmin и в php

Comment: И как это исправить? Простое добавление еще одного \ не помогло.

Comment: либо кавычки меняй местами, одинарные и двойные, что бы не было экранирования, либо каждый \ меняй на два, в итоге \\ заменить на \\\\

Comment: заменил \\ на / и заработало. спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать следующие настройки в php.ini

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638090/load-data-local-infile-forbidden-in-php/

```
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```